# How can I write an Autohotkey script that acts like both mouse buttons are continuously held down, if I hold down one mouse button?

Tags: autohotkey

1st time post here.  So I have this script so far.

```
CAPSLOCK::Suspend
lbutton::  ; 
{
MouseCLick, Left
MouseClick, Right
}
```

I wanted to have my left click act as if i'm clicking both left click and right click at the same time.  While this works, it only registers as 1 click. Is there a script I can add that if I hold down left click, it will act as if i'm holding down both left click and right click at the same time and if I let go, it stops?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the state of the mouse

```
GetKeyState, keystate, Lbutton,P
if keystate = U
   break
```

[Source and more detail](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/37376-loop-while-mouse-pressed/)

I suspect you'll need *something* like (copied from the above source, but modified)

```
*~LButton::
; ~makes it execute the LeftClick like normal then the script kicks in
; * means it will also work while holding other keys like shift
Sleep 500
loop{

;check 3x every Xms if the button got released
Sleep 200
GetKeyState, keystate, Lbutton,P
if keystate = U
    break
Sleep 200
GetKeyState, keystate, Lbutton,P
if keystate = U
    break
Sleep 200
GetKeyState, keystate, Lbutton,P
if keystate = U
    break
else
; do the click then loop
    MouseClick, left
    MouseClick, Right
}
return
```

Comment: This seems to be not working.

Comment: Nevermind.  I figured it out.  Thx guys.